# How do I DataBind a DataGrid after reading serial port

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, serial-port

I am trying to read from a serial port and put the data into a grid.
and the data doesn't appear in the data grid.

I used notify changer per martin comment below.

only wanted to show the data on the datagrid view when serial port is updated.

here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="689.7" Width="655">

<Grid Margin="0,0,2,9">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridData" Margin="50,25,19,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=FirstName}">            
    </DataGrid>        


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is the CS:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;
  using System.IO.Ports;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
  using System.ComponentModel;

  namespace WpfApplication2
  {
 /// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };


    /// <summary>
    /// this class contain a row for the data to show in the dataGridRecieved
    /// </summary>
    public class DataForTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private string time; // contain the time of the data that has been sent or recieved. 

        /// <summary>
        /// get or sets the time that has been recieved.
        /// </summary>
        public string Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { time = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
            }
        }


        private string data; // contain the line of data the has been recieved.                        

        /// <summary>
        /// get or set the line of data that has been send to recieved
        /// </summary>
        public string Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
            }
        }




    }




    private System.Threading.Thread threadSerial;
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _sp;
    private Queue<byte[]> _QbytesFromSerialPort1;
    private Queue<DateTime> _QDateTimeFromSerialPort1;      
    private byte[] _RealBytesFromSerialPort;
    private delegate void emptydelagte(); // delegate to pass on the play option.
    private emptydelagte updateTableGuiDelgate;                
    public DataForTable _dataForTable;

    private Thread GUIThread;
    object lockMessage;



    private ObservableCollection  <DataForTable> _firstName;
    public ObservableCollection<DataForTable> FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                                    

        _QbytesFromSerialPort1 = new Queue<byte[]>();
        _QDateTimeFromSerialPort1 = new Queue<DateTime>();

        _firstName = new ObservableCollection<DataForTable>();
         _dataForTable = new DataForTable();
        // DataGridData.ItemsSource = _firstName.Select(DataForTable => new { DataForTable.Data, DataForTable.Time }).ToList();


        //create serial port
        _sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 38400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _sp.Open();
        threadSerial = new Thread(new ThreadStart(readSerialPort)); //reads from serial port.
        threadSerial.IsBackground = true;
        threadSerial.Start();

        //updateTableGuiDelgate = new emptydelagte(updateTableGuiDelgate);
        GUIThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GuIThread));
        GUIThread.IsBackground = true;
        GUIThread.Start();





    }


    private void readSerialPort()
    {
        _RealBytesFromSerialPort = new byte[100];
        DateTime _dtRead = new DateTime();
        lockMessage = 0;
        while (true)
        {                
            if (_sp.IsOpen)
            {

                if (_sp.BytesToRead > 0)
                {

                    lock (lockMessage)
                    {

                        _RealBytesFromSerialPort = new byte[_sp.BytesToRead];
                        _sp.Read(_RealBytesFromSerialPort, 0, _sp.BytesToRead); //read data
                        if (_RealBytesFromSerialPort.Length != 0)
                        {
                            _dtRead = DateTime.Now;


                            _QbytesFromSerialPort1.Enqueue(_RealBytesFromSerialPort); // q from serial porta                                                                
                            _QDateTimeFromSerialPort1.Enqueue(_dtRead); // q from date time now.
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] tmp;

    private void GuIThread()
    {

        _dataForTable = new DataForTable();
        while (true)
        {

                if (_QbytesFromSerialPort1.Count > 0)
                {
                    _dataForTable.Data = byteToString(_QbytesFromSerialPort1.Dequeue());
                    _dataForTable.Time = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();              
                    _firstName.Add(_dataForTable);                       
                 //   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateTableGuiDelgate);
                }

        }



    }


    private string byteToString(byte [] arr)
    {
        string tmps = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            tmps += arr[i].ToString()  + " ";
        }

        return tmps;
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I do not know whether this is the only problem, but in any case you need to change the property you use as `ItemsSource`. It needs to be a public property, so change `_firstName` to `FirstName` and make it a public property.

Comment: Still didn't help same error...

Comment: Please update your code example first (the public property).Have your tried debugging your `GuIThread` method? It adds the items in this line: _firstName.Add(_dataForTable); In addition I would recommend you to first add some static content (items) to the DataGrid just to test whether the binding works and when you see that it works fill the DataGrid with real data from the `GuIThread` method.

Comment: I updated the code, however I want the _firstName to add rows, so why I need to delete it?

Comment: I am trying to narrow down the error. So I suggested commenting out the start of the `GuIThread` method and add some test content to your DataGrid and see whether this works. By the way, since your adding the items one by one, you also need to change your property from List to ObservableCollection and you should also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `MainWindow` class because your are using it as binding source.

Comment: fixed the error however I can see the data in the datagrid. update the code again

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add data from another thread:

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridBInding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataTableItem> _Items;

    public ObservableCollection<DataTableItem> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataTableItem>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    Items.Add(new DataTableItem() { Data = "Data " + i });
            }
        );
        });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

And the DataTableItem class:

```
public class DataTableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Data;

    public string Data
    {
        get { return _Data; }
        set
        {
            _Data = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

In order for the UI to be informed of newly items added, you need to use the ObservableCollection instead of that simple List.

One more thing, SerialPort class has a DataReceived event, wouldn't that be more suited here instead of polling ?

Further more, try to simplify the way you are going back to the GUI thread, it's a bit difficult to follow and it shouldn't be. In my example i have used a lambda expression on that Invoke. Check it out!

Comment: I change it see above and still doesn't work. and as far as I understand dataReceived event can cause dead lock